# Change component visual behavior on Windows 10 themed project

Tags: delphi

I have a specific visual component that I want to change his behavior on my project. I'm using Windows 10 theme on my project, that makes change the behavior of visual components. I have buttons inside edits, but their height overflows the edit height. All I want to do, is to decrease the height with 1 or 2 pixels for all buttons in my project.

Comment: Which Delphi version and VCL or FMX project? You have presumably tried to set the `Height` property of the buttons?

Comment: VCL project. I know the height property of the button, but i have many forms in project, do it manually would take alot of my time.

Comment: There's nothing in the IDE to help you, so 1) at form creation traverse through all components in the form, and set the height, or 2) create a simple utility program that goes through all .dfm files (assuming they are in text mode) and again when encountering a button, change its height. I have no idea of your skill level, so I must warn you that 2) may turn your forms to a disaster if you make a mistake.

Comment: The `Height` property determines a control's height. Modify it.

Comment: I know Height property, but how change from all project? Will i do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call this function for all your forms (e.g. when you create or show them)

```
procedure ResizeButtons(F: TForm; DH: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to F.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if (F.Components[I] is TButton) then
      TButton(F.Components[I]).Height := TButton(F.Components[I]).Height + DH;
end;
```

...

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ResizeButtons(Self, -1);
end;
```

Comment: It's a nice solution too